# json payload coming through with null members

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending a json payload into my WebApi action. For a while, the parameter was null, but then I changed the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and now the object comes through, but all of its members are null or default values

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seding a JSON payload then the content type should be `Content-Type: application/json`.

If you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like you do now, you are forcing a use of a formatter that's not capable of reading a JSON input.

Comment: sigh... ok so I was using application/json before and it was coming through as a null object. I just changed it back to application/json and it it working again. Thanks.